# Tests - both classes share the same login code but it only works in one

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I'm writing tests for locallibrary app following the tutorial on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing). Both classes that test views share similar login code, but it only works in one class

I tried finding spelling errors and comping both classes

Code snippets:

Login throws FAIL:

```
class AuthorCreateViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create two users
        test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='fjo&*&d3h')
        test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='J9cdj8we9')

        test_user1.save()

        # Give test_user2 permission to renew books.
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Set book as returned')
        test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
        test_user2.save()

    def test_view_url_accessible_by_name(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='J9cdj8we9')
        
        response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Login works:

```
class RenewBookInstancesViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create two users
        test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='fjo&*&d3h')
        test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='J9cdj8we9')

        test_user1.save()
        test_user2.save()

        # Give test_user2 permission to renew books.
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Set book as returned')
        test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
        test_user2.save()

    def test_logged_in_with_permission_borrowed_book(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='J9cdj8we9')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('renew-book-librarian', kwargs={'pk':self.test_bookinstance2.pk}))

        # Check that it lets us login - this is our book and we have the right permissions.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here is the [github link](https://github.com/ra2dd/locallibrary/blob/master/catalog/tests/test_views.py) with all code in classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Incorrect Permissions Being Set**

The permission is wrong here:

```py
class AuthorCreateViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create two users
        test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='fjo&*&d3h')
        test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='J9cdj8we9')

        test_user1.save()

        # Give test_user2 permission to renew books.
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Set book as returned')
        test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
        test_user2.save()
```

because in this test, which is the first that fails

```py
def test_logged_in_with_correct_permission(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser4', password='9dj2q8f')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

you are redirecting to `author-create`, but the permission there is NOT `Set book as returned`, rather `Add or modify book records and information about them`, thus change it to this:

```py
class AuthorCreateViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create two users
        test_user3 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser3', password='nd392dn')
        test_user4 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser4', password='9dj2q8f')

        # Give test_user2 permission to renew books.
        # permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Set book as returned')
        # test_user4.user_permissions.add(permission)
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Add or modify book records and information about them')
        test_user4.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Also, as an aside, both `create_user` and `add` save by default, so it is not necessary to do `test_user4.save()` in these.  I'm not sure why the MDN tutorial is showing that.